# Assumption and simple calculation

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I'm having an issue with what seems to be an simple question.
Here it is:

Two hockey teams, team A and team B played a game, Team A beat Team B by 2 goals. The crowd was pleased as there were 8 goals in total for the whole game.

What was the game's scored?

How many goals did team A score and how many did Team B?

My first thought was that because the total goals in the game were 8 and team A won by 2 goals they must had 6 goals and team B had 2 because if team B had scored those 2 last goals they would have a tie. But I'm still confused is my assumptions are right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Set up.
$(1)$ $A-B=2$
$(2)$ $A+B=8$
Solve.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $5:3$,

Let's denote  $A'$ be the number of goals of team $A$,

and let $B'$ be the number of goals of team $B$

Team $A$ beat Team $B$ by $2$ goals: so $A'=B'+2$ and we also know that $A'+B'=8$

So have two equations with two variables:

$$\begin{cases}
A'=B'+2\\
A'+B'=8
\end{cases}$$

So from the first row we get $A'=B'+2$, let set that in the second row we get

$B'+2+B'=8$ so $B'=3$ and $A'=5$

Comment: Posts giving just the answer are rarely helpful. Could you include information on how the OP could get the answer from his question?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I edited

Comment: Much better! +1

Answer (score 0):

Call $x$ the number of the team A goals. Then B made $x-2$ goals. The total goals are $x+(x-2)=8$ then $x=5$

Comment: (+1) This answer does not deserved a downvote

Comment: Thanks I was also wondering why, but seeing the downvote on the pther answers I guessed it came from a frustrated (\not even a 3rd grade or lower) mind

Answer (score 0):

If I may, how did you deduce that Team A scored 6 goals and team B scored 2. There were 8 goals TOTAL for the entire game. And we know the condition $$Ascore= Bscore+2$$ Knowing that, recall what the total score was and deduce your answer by system of equations.